# Custom types with import not working with typescript

Tags: typescript, import, definitelytyped

So I'm writing my own typings file for my application. I have a folder @types in the root. Everytinh works fine: I've updated the tsconfig to let webpack and my ide know where to find the typings.

On of my vars defined in the interace should be fron a type of a external library. But when I import the specific type into the typings file, the typings file gets corrupted or something, because none of the defined interfaces can be found in my application anymore!

```
import {GraphQLError} from '../../node_modules/@types/graphql/error/GraphQLError';

interface IResponse{
  data?: {
    views: Array<IViewScheme>
  };
  errors?: Array<GraphQLError>;
  loading: boolean;
}
```

I've tried differentpaths as well, like @types/graphql etc. But all keeps failing. When i rmeove the import, everything is fine...

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "graphql",
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack",
      "vizceral"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide information regarding your environment such as your `tsconfig.json` to understand why the error may be occuring